# RewriteRule overrides ProxyPass

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, proxypass

On a centos 7 machine, I'd like to run a python server alongside an apache server. I figured the easiest way would be to configure apache as a reverse proxy. This is my VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /home/username/mydomain/src
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ErrorLog logs/mydomain-error_log
        CustomLog logs/mydomain-access_log common
        DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /home/username/mydomain/src>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
    </Directory>


    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /mediaproxy http://127.0.0.1:9001/mediaproxy
    ProxyPassReverse /mediaproxy http://127.0.0.1:9001/mediaproxy

    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/api/media/(.*) /data/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/api/v1/* /api/v1/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*) /site/v1/content/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /site/v1/content/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /site/v1/content/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/fonts/(.*) /site/v1/content/fonts/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/* /index.php [L] # problematic rule

    // lets encrypt entries
```

Now, my problem is that rewrite rules takes precedence over ProxyPass. That ism when I visit mydomain.com/mediaproxy/somepage, it serves the content at `/index.php`, specified with `RewriteRule ^/* /index.php [L]` . Reverse proxy works correctly if I remove the problematic rule. Unfortunately I need to keep it.

How do I tell apache to use `ProxyPass` rule first, and use `RewriteRule` only if there is no match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/* /index.php [L] # problematic rule
> ```

Your rule rewrites *everything*. You could just make an exception for the URL-path you want to proxy. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^/mediaproxy /index.php [L]
```

The `!` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* negates the expression. So it is successful when it does *not* match.

This now rewrites everything *except* URL-paths that start `/mediaproxy`.

Note that the trailing `*` quantifier in the regex `^/*` repeats the preceding token 0 or more times. The preceding token in this instance is the slash. You are missing the preceding `.` (dot). Or omit the `.*` entirely as it's superfluous (and less efficient).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^/api/media/(.*) /data/$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^/api/v1/* /api/v1/index.php [L]
> RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*) /site/v1/content/assets/$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /site/v1/content/css/$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /site/v1/content/js/$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^/fonts/(.*) /site/v1/content/fonts/$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^/* /index.php [L] # problematic rule
> ```

The two *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) are not doing anything here. When used in a virtualhost context, `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the same as `REQUEST_URI`, since it is processed early, before the request is mapped to the filesystem. Consequently, both (negated) *conditions* will always be successful and the following rule is always processed. In a vhost context you need to use a lookahead, ie. `LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME`, OR construct the file-path using the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` server variable, OR move the rules into a *directory* context.

However, those two conditions only apply to the first rule that follows. So all the remaining rules (including the last "problematic" rule) are processed unconditionally anyway. This is generally incorrect for a front-controller pattern (the last rule) and should perhaps be written like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule !^/mediaproxy /index.php [L]
```

This now rewrites everything except URL-paths that do not start `/mediaproxy` AND do not map to a directory AND do not map to a file.

Alternatively, if these *condtions* should be applied to all rules then create a negated rule instead. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

# Prevent further processing if root directory or "index.php" requested
RewriteRule ^/(index\.php)?$ - [L]

# Prevent further processing if the request maps to a directory or file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/. - [L]

RewriteRule ^/api/media/(.*) /data/$1 [L]

# This rule is not required since the DirectoryIndex handles this case (the regex is also "incorrect").
#RewriteRule ^/api/v1/* /api/v1/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*) /site/v1/content/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /site/v1/content/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /site/v1/content/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/fonts/(.*) /site/v1/content/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule !^/mediaproxy /index.php [L]
```